# Qt5 and OpenCv 4

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I want to use the OpenCv framework with Qt Applications on Linux (Debian). From https://opencv.org/releases.html I've downloaded the opencv-4.0.1.zip and unzip it into a folder. Then using CMake GUI I've configured the build with BUILD_opencv_world option marked. Then I generate the build and with compiled the library with `make` and `make install` and everything seems to be fine.

I've created a opencv.pri file with:

```
INCLUDE += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_world
```

To test OpenCv I've created a Qt command line project and try to load an image and display, here the QtCvTest.pro

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp

include(/home/stefano/opencv-4.0.1/opencv.pri)
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "QtCvTest Start";

    using namespace cv;

    Mat image;
    image = imread("/home/stefano/Pictures/2018/02/27/DSC_1421.JPG",  CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if(! image.data )     {
        qDebug() <<  "Could not open or find the image";
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Test", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Test", image );


    qDebug() << "QtCvTest End";

    return a.exec();
}
```

If I try to compile I get the following error

```
main.cpp:22: error: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
```

any idea how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: change  `INCLUDE` to `INCLUDEPATH`, change `-lopencv_world` to `-lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs`

Comment: Or use: `CONFIG += link_pkgconfig`  `PKGCONFIG += opencv4`

Comment: Now it works! I've changed to `INCLUDEPATH` and added the link to opencv_imgproc, opencv_core and opencv_highgui. If I add also opencv_imgcodecs I get an error (-1: error: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It seems that when you compiled you did not disable a flag that compiles that binary, it does not matter

Comment: If I try to use the `CONFIG` I get the error _opencv4 development package not found_

Comment: try with: `PKGCONFIG += opencv`

Comment: in my case I have the old versions of opencv together with opencv4 so the .pc in my case is called opencv4.pc.

Comment: Ok, now it works also with `PKGCONFIG += opencv` Which is the best way to use OpenCv?

Comment: with PKGCONFIG + = opencv you are adding all the -l{libs} so your executable is probably very heavy unlike if you add one by one as in the first case so for development use PKGCONFIG and for production I only link the necessary ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use INCLUDEPATH and the necessary flags for reading and displaying the image in a window:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui
```